# Not able to Hide Keyboard on search button click for Iphone application

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am new to xcode development I am creating a simple application. In that I have table view Controller with on Search bar control. `onClick` of Search bar Key board comes up I am not able to hide the key board. I tried to Hide it by

```
(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{       

[self resignFirstResponder];    
[self.searchbar setShowsCancelButton: NO animated: YES]; 

}
```

but It is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide keyboard, you should lose focus on the text input, not the class instance itself (self)

In your case, you should do

```
[searchBar resignFirstResponder]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

In your button's action.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
if([text length] == 0) {
    [searchBar performSelector: @selector(resignFirstResponder)
                       withObject: nil
                       afterDelay: 0.1];
}
```

where text is searchbar text

Best of luck